# How could I get the buttons on the left?

Tags: jquery, html, css, skel

I am trying to create a reference website. I am using new framework called "Skel". Its really cool, but there is no specific documentation. I'm wondering how to get the buttons on the navigational bar to be next to the title, instead of the right. Here is the code I am using:

```
<header id="header" class="skel-layers-fixed">
    <h1><a href="#">Reference</a></h1>
    <nav id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#top">Top</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="page2.html">References</a></li>
            <li><a href="page3.html">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Here is the nav bar contents in the style.css

```
#header nav {
    height: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    right: 1.25em;
    top: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#header nav > ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

#header nav > ul > li {
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 1em;
    padding-left: 0;
}

#header nav > ul > li a {
    -moz-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    color: #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#header nav > ul > li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

#header nav > ul > li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}

#header nav > ul > li .button {
    height: 2.25em;
    line-height: 2.25em;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 0 1em;
    position: relative;
    top: -0.075em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#header .container {
    position: relative;
}

#header .container h1 {
    left: 0;
}

#header .container nav {
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to modify your CSS a little bit. First of all, specify the following styles for the heading inside the header:

```
#header h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Specifying the `display` property of `h1` to be `display: inline-block` allows other elements to appear in the same line as the heading.

Next, you will need to remove existing CSS which you're using for `#header nav` and use the following styles:

```
#header nav {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Here's a working example:

```css
#header nav {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#header h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#header nav > ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
#header nav > ul > li {
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 1em;
  padding-left: 0;
}
#header nav > ul > li a {
  -moz-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  color: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#header nav > ul > li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
#header nav > ul > li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
#header nav > ul > li .button {
  height: 2.25em;
  line-height: 2.25em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0 1em;
  position: relative;
  top: -0.075em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#header .container {
  position: relative;
}
#header .container h1 {
  left: 0;
}
#header .container nav {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<header id="header" class="skel-layers-fixed">
  <h1><a href="#">Reference</a></h1>

  <nav id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#top">Top</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="page2.html">References</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="page3.html">About</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Fahad, how could I get it about 150 pixels away from the title? http://gyazo.com/62bb99a8f1b8dfeb76636ed4de9300a7

Comment: You can either add `margin-left: 150px` to `#header nav` or `margin-right: 150px` to `#header h1`. The picture whose link you've given above, is that how it appears on your website after making the CSS changes which I've specified above?

Comment: No, I rolled it back so it would be easier to understand.

Comment: What results did you get when you applied my CSS? Also, are you doing the development on some live website? If yes, can you share its link?

Comment: No, but I can. Give me one second.